# HTTP 403 when trying to create sql user using gcloud cli

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I've done a `gcloud auth login` as well as `gcloud auth application-default login`.

However I'm trying to create SQL user with:
`gcloud sql users create proxyuser2 cloudsqlproxy~% --instance=wordpress-test` which returns an error of:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.users.create) HTTPError 403: The client is not authorized to make this request.
```

I'm able to create a SQL user via the web console though.

Why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong instance name... `wordpress-test` instead of `wordpresstest`.